# How to parse id to another page with GET

Tags: php, mysql

How exactly work parsing data with GET and URL?
In first page I have mass.php:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2))
{
   $id = $row["id"];
   $text = $row["text"];
   $date = $row["date"];

   echo "nl2br($row['text']) . "<br /><br />";
   echo '<div id="data">Submitted on ' . $row['date'] . "</div>";
   echo '<a href="single.php?id='. row['$id'] .'">More...</a>';
}
```

$row['text'] refer to row text in database and I trying to parse to single.php.

Problem is when I take 'id' to single.php and echo i get exact 'id' from mysql. How to take the text?

edit:

That's it single.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include 'include/db.php';
  print_r($_GET);
?>
```

edit2:

On mess.php I have 5 post/news. They are 40 characters long with link 'More...". When user click on 'More...' on some news will open single.php with this particularly news. Now it's when open single.php there is id of this news not text.

Comment: [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: there are 2 options, one to send text as you have send id like id=<id>&text=<text> BUT this is not a good practice. Second, you fetch the text from db on single.php by using id which you received in $_GET['id'];

Comment: How can I fetch the text using id in single.php?

Comment: @Gordon `$_GET['id']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

`<a href="single.php?id='. row['$id'] .'">More...</a>`

By

`<a href="single.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">More...</a>`

Recommend that you use this in your pages:

`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

In single.php use:

`echo $_GET['id'];`

Read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

If you're tempted to skip to the main variable "$ row" to another page, you have 2 options:

**1 Option -** Use `$_GET`:

Your link:

`<a href="single.php?id='. $row['id'] .'&amp;text='. $row['text'] .'">More...</a>`

In single.php:

```
echo $_GET['id'];
echo '<br>';
echo $_GET['text'];
```

---

**2 Option -** Use mysql in single.php:

Your link:

`<a href="single.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">More...</a>`

In single.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include 'include/db.php';
  ...
  if($q = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` = ' . mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']))){
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
      echo $row['text'];
    } else {
      echo 'Not found';
    }
  } else {
    echo mysqli_error();
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use just $id instead of row['$id']